# mui-datatables can't disable selectableRows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I created a table with mui-datatables. Everything is working fine, except setting selectableRows in the options. It throws the following error:

> Type '{ selectableRows: boolean; }' is not assignable to type
> 'Partial<{ caseSensitive: boolean; confirmFilters: boolean;
> columnOrder: number[]; count: number; customFilterDialogFooter:
> (filterList: string[][], applyNewFilters?: ((...args: any[]) => any) |
> undefined) => ReactNode; ... 80 more ...; viewColumns: ToolbarButton;
> }>'.   Types of property 'selectableRows' are incompatible.
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'SelectableRows | undefined'.  TS2322

```
 const columns = [
      {
           name: "id",
           label: "ID",
           options: {
                filter: true,
                sort: true,
           }
      },
      {
           name: "val",
           label: "val",
           options: {
                filter: true,
                sort: true,
           }
      },
      {
           name: "zip",
           label: "zip",
           options: {
                filter: true,
                sort: true,
           }
      }
 ];

 const options = {
      selectableRows: false
 };

 return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
           <MUIDataTable
           title={""}
           data={rows}
           columns={columns}
           options={options}
           />
      </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is `isRowSelectable`

Here is a copy of the document.

> **`isRowSelectable`**: Enable/disable selection on certain rows with custom function. Returns `true` if not provided. `function(dataIndex: number, selectedRows: object(lookup: {dataindex: boolean}, data: arrayOfObjects: {index, dataIndex})) => boolean`.

so technically you need to pass a function to this option. And in that function, you can access to `dataIndex,selectedRows,data` as arguments and  return with a boolean that checks your own criteria.

So ideally it should look like this:

```js
  isRowSelectable: (dataIndex, selectedRows, data) => {
    return (
     dataArray[dataIndex].required === false
    )
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best approach, but setting **selectableRowsHideCheckboxes** to **false** did it to me.